# How to fix error missing php_mbstring.dll while install composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am newbie of Laravel programming. I have got error while try to install Composer on CMD in Windows as bellow :

[image]

I have been searching on Google to find out way of fix this error but I can not still get solution. Please help me.

Comment: Please let us know which solutions you've tried. Also where do you get composer from, which version is that, what process you followed to install it?

Comment: I downloaded the composer from https://getcomposer.org/download/ and try to install this as in Vietnamese tutorial as follows : copy composer.phar into source folder of Laravel after that run the command " php composer.phar install" in command line mode in Windows...then i Have got above error

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have php_mbstring.dll in your PHP/ext folder. Also you need to check you have uncommented line extension=php_mbstring.dll in your php.ini.

Comment: Because I work on Laravel and I try to install Composer by copying this into source folder Laravel so I can not find out php.ini in source folder. The webserver that I use is Appserv (version 2.5)